# Usb 3.0 on front panel

Tags: case

So i recently built my rig and i used this case https://ms-start.com/en/ms-phantom-midi-tower-case.aspx . And it does not have usb 3.0 on the front panel but it does have a cut out thing on the far left of the front panel as you can see on the pics.
My question is can i somehow add it there or do i need something like this [https://www.amazon.com/Kingwin-Include-Charging-Transfer-Computer/dp/B01AJTOLRY/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01AJTOLRY)

Comment: I think you’re referring to the _something_ in the upper left corner of the front? I don’t think this is removable. It could be the reset switch or something.

Answer (score 2):

1. That usb panel is for a 5.25" slot, which that PC case has 1, usually for an optical drive. So you would have to decide, do you want front usb 3.0 or an Optical drive (CD-DVD-Bluray).
2. That USB panel gives no indication of how it connects or if it has its own usb 3.0 controller, nor can I find any information for that model.
3. If that panel does not have its own controller for USB 3.0 it will have to be plugged into your motherboard 20 Pin USB 3.0 port if it has one, if it does not your will have to purchase a [pci express 1x 3.0 add in card](https://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-3-0-PCI-Express-2-Ports-Front-Panel-with-Control-Adapter-Card-4-Pin-20-Pin/264492565745?hash=item3d94fc44f1:g:sNEAAOSwwrFdaiw7) that has at least one 20 pin header. That is if your motherboard has a pci-e 1x slot.
4. That is not a cut out, its a label as far as I can tell.
5. If you don't mind having USB 3.0 ports on the back of the case then I suggest a card [like this one](https://www.ebay.com/itm/SIIG-4-Port-USB-3-0-PCle-Full-Height-PCI-Express-4-Port-USB-3-0-Host-Adapter-NEW/113995452974?epid=1600128439&hash=item1a8aa8922e:g:w44AAOSw9-ldloNN), This has the correct power connection, most from china have molex legacy power connection which requires a sata power to molex adapter.

Answer (score 0):

The "a cut out thing" you mentioned is a cover of 5.25" external slot and it's removable. You can get Kingwin Front Panel USB 3.0 Hub and insert there to have USB 3.0 ports in the front because it fits any 5.25" computer case front bay.

However, if your motherboard doesn't have USB 3.0 connector to connect the wire of Kingwin into, then you need to purchase a PCI Express USB 3.0 card, [like this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GSQR6D4).